# How to compute 15-min standard deviations of a minutely dataset?

Tags: python, list, std

I have one array, raytimes, which is a fraction of an hour, e.g., [0, 0.1, 0.2... 0.9, 1.0].
I have another list of floats, which is my velocity vr. Each data time corresponds to a list of velocities as a function of height.

I'm trying to compute a 15-min standard deviation of velocity from this velocity dataset, and keep it so that the std is performed at each height level (so I should have an array of the standard deviations, one for each height).

raytimes is time [0, 0.1, 0.2... 0.9, 1.0].
vr is a 108 list of 2500 float64 numbers. The 2500 numbers correspond to the velocity measured at each height (on a fixed height grid). 
I don't know how to separate the chunks of data such that I can compute std on just the first, second, third, and fourth 15-min intervals. 
THEN I need to compute the std at each specific height level.

```
for i in raytimes:
    if raytimes[i] < 0.25:
        w1 = w1.append(vr)
    if raytimes[i] > 0.25 & raytimes < 0.5:
        w2 = w2.append(vr)
    if raytimes[i] > 0.5 & raytimes < 0.75:
        w3 = w3.append(vr)
    if raytimes[i] < 1:
        w4 = w4.append(vr)
sigma_w1 = std(w1)
sigma_w2 = std(w2)
etc...
```

Problem is in my above code I am appending the entire vr matrix. How do I only append the list of vrs that correspond to times within the 15min chunk? 
And then how to I compute the std maintaining the height grid, so the std is computed along each height? I should end up with the same array size of 2500.

Comment: You should be using `if...elif...elif...else` rather than `if...if...if...if`. As it is now, your last condition is independent from your earlier conditions. You also ignore cases where the number is exactly on one of the boundaries, e.g., you don't have any `<=` or `>=`

Comment: Can you explain again the two arrays? Raytimes is just a 1 dimensional array of length 11 right? Then you have an array vr containing measurements of velocity? You talk about them corresponding to a particular time and height but you haven't told us how you tell which time each vr element is from and you haven't explained where the height comes from at all. The number 108 just appears in the middle of a sentence, what's that about?

Comment: Thanks for the elif tip - will do. 
Yes, raytimes is a 1-dimensional list of length 108.
Vr is a 108-dimesional list of floats, each of length 2500.
Height is a list of length 2500 and its value never changes. 
Thus there is a vr for each time, at each height. 
I hope that clarifies it?

Comment: Ok, so you've measured velocity at 108 different times at 2500 different heights? How do you have 108 times in raytimes if it goes from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.1? I'll write you an answer in a bit, but just for my info how did the data get in this format? This type of scientific computing typically uses numpy arrays or pandas data frames rather than lists as they make it easier to solve problems like yours.

Comment: I agree this is a brutal way to do the code - there must be a more elegant solution where i can just group the VRs based on time then compute STD at each height....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the start of an answer which I can refine based on your feedback. Note this is not really a great way to actually transform the data, I'm just trying to demonstrate how to move your code toward something which gives the answer you want. Here I've assumed that you want an SD grouped by height and 15-minute period; so that's 10000 results. If you actually wanted the SD over height or some other grouping function let me know in the comments. I've also assumed from what you said above that vr is a list of lists. Specifically a list of length 108 of lists of length 2500. If that's not right, leave a comment.

EDIT - I realised there's a fundamental mistake in how you are using the for loop which I had inadvertently copied. You are using i as the index, but i is the actual value of the item. If you want the position of the item, you need to use enumerate. See my example below, I've made i the index and t the value for raytimes.

EDIT 2 - approach remains the same but I've actually run this code so I've corrected all the various mistakes that you and I had made in the previous iteration. Can you try this with your data and confirm that the output is correct, then we can look at how you need the output presented.

EDIT 3 - added four results lists to hold the output as requested

```
from statistics import pstdev
#remove these lines, these are just test data
raytimes=[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
heights=[1,2]
vr=[[4,3],[5,3],[3,5],[4,1],[8,2],[2,3],[1,4],[9,5],[7,3],[6,7],[3,8]]
#initialise empty arrays
w1 = []
w2 = []
w3 = []
w4 = []
r1 = []
r2 = []
r3 = []
r4 = []


for j, h in enumerate(heights):
    for i, t in enumerate(raytimes):
        if raytimes[i] < 0.25:
            w1.append(vr[i][j])
        elif 0.25 < raytimes[i] < 0.5:
            w2.append(vr[i][j])
        elif 0.5 < raytimes[i] < 0.75:
            w3.append(vr[i][j])
        else:
            w4.append(vr[i][j])
    print(w1,w2,w3,w4)
    print("First Period - Height: ", str(h), " SD: ", str(pstdev(w1)))
    r1.append(pstdev(w1))
    print("Second Period - Height: ", str(h), " SD: ", str(pstdev(w2)))
    r2.append(pstdev(w2))
    print("Third Period - Height: ", str(h), " SD: ", str(pstdev(w3)))
    r3.append(pstdev(w3))
    print("Fourth Period - Height: ", str(h), " SD: ", str(pstdev(w4)))
    r4.append(pstdev(w4))
    w1 = []
    w2 = []
    w3 = []
    w4 = []
```

Comment: Thanks, this certainly gets me much closer! To answer your question: raytimes is 108; the example I used (0.1, 0.2) is just an example. It actually is more like (0.01, 0.019, etc.). 

I need the SD over height. The array w1, w2, etc., is currently 1x67473. I need to separate each 'ray' out so that I can take the std at each height.
w1 should be an array of arrays, with each array having the same structure as vr [1x2500]. I should have ~27 arrays each for w1 to w4, each of length 2500. Then I need to take the std of 27 numbers for each height (2500x) to get the std as a function of height.

Comment: Updated code: 
w1 = []
w2 = []
w3 = []
w4 = []
    for j,h in enumerate(Height):    
        for i,t in enumerate(raytimes):
            if raytimes[i] <= 0.25:
                w1.append(float(vr[i][j]))
            elif (raytimes[i] > 0.25) & (raytimes[i] <= 0.5):
                w2.append(float(vr[i][j]))
            elif (raytimes[i] > 0.5) & (raytimes[i] <= 0.75):
                w3.append(float(vr[i][j]))
            else:
                w4.append(float(vr[i][j]))

Comment: however I can't figure out how to separate out the w1. I tried concantenate but no luck. I want to assign w1[X] = append(vr[i][j]) where X is each new ray

Comment: Ok, the good news is that what I was trying to do in my answer seems to match your requirements. The bad news is that because I forgot to clear out w1, w2, w3 etc between each loop over height they will just get longer and longer which wasn't my intention. I was intending that you'd get 10000 lines printed from this, each for one height, for one of your four periods, which I think is what you want. I'll try to revisit my answer. Now you're making progress I'd really recommend you look at numpy arrays instead of lists as I think they'd match your ear or thinking much better.

Comment: OK thanks. Yes I agree arrays would be much easier - not sure if it makes sense to switch the code to arrays now (too late?) or finish with what I have now. 
Yes I see w1s just get longer; I'm just not sure how to parse it out properly. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I've updated my answer again. I probably wouldn't bother switching to numpy at this stage as the differences will be pretty small. However, you might want to consider working with data like this in a database (or pandas, which give you database-like structures in Python). The big advantage there is that the data is actually meaningfully attached to the labels so you can simply query the data based on the labels (for example 'give me the SD of the data in fifteen minute chunks by height' rather than having to handle the indexes etc yourself.

Comment: Thanks this great, except that I need to store these SDs in an array and not just print them. I believe I should end up with an array of length 2500 (one array of SDs for the time period, at each height). 
Before the w1=[] commands I tried:  wtest[j][h] = pstdev(w1[h]) but of course it doesn't work to pre-allocate wtest[j][h], I need to store it some other way?
Or I need to do something similar to store this array of SDs somewhere, not just print them. That's the issue I was having.

Comment: *SD value at each height

Comment: Original answer amended yet again, think we're done :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, we can do that. So your expected output is a 2500-long list of 4-long lists right? 10000 values in total? I think the issue you are having is that you're trying to assign values outside the range of the list, you can't grow a list that way.

Edit - oops this wasn't supposed to be an answer. Mistook it for the comment box on mobile. Nevermind

Comment: Yes that's correct! How can I grow a list using this data format then? I'm trying to figure out how to (1) compute SD at each height so I am left with one SD at each height level, leaving me with a 1x2500 list (for each 15-min time interval). Then I need to (2) store this data, lets call it w1_sd (1x2500), so I can output to text file later (this I can do).

Comment: Your answer is actually slightly different from my suggestion. In a list of lists 4 lists of 2500 is different from 2500 lists of 4, but no matter, its all doable. Do you specifically need separate text files for each 2500? Is there any reason why you want to hold them in lists first? We could just write each value out as we iterate through the data.

Comment: That's it, thank you! You were a ton of help. I'm going to read up on pandas and how to do this all properly. Much appreciated!!